# how to reduce noise or filter out noise with k-means clustering algorithm? DBSCAN?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have 7 known centroids shape=(7,4) and a numpy array of shape=(160000, 4).

If I remove one data set from the numpy array and just use 6 centroids then the kmeans cluster algorithm works quite well. If I include the dataset that has noisy data, then the kmeans clustering algorithm runs into issues.

What are some recommended ways of reducing noise or filtering it out with scikit-learn kmeans clustering?

As an alternative, I have considered using the dbscan algorithm http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html

I did also try to use init=initial_centroids but that did not seem to make a difference

```
    #numpy array containing noise
    data_with_noise.shape=(160000,4)  
    centroids= sk.KMeans(n_clusters=7, init='k-means++', max_iter=1000)
    #this data set gives errors 
    centroids.fit_transform(data_with_noise)

    #works well but only for 6 clusters  
    no_noise_centroids= sk.KMeans(n_clusters=6, init='k-means++', max_iter=1000)
    no_noise_centroids.fit(data_no_noise)
```

Comment: If you add noisy data that spans the whole parameter space, it will affect the clusters that k-means finds (recall that it will _always_ find k clusters). You can use a PCA method to first reduce the set to a simpler parameter space. This will drastically reduce the effects of noise at the cost of possibly providing different classifications (clusters).

Comment: @Tim Why would PCA reduce the effects of noise? PCA itself is rather sensitive to outliers (= noise).

Comment: thanks, is there an example of pca that you recommend? I am just going over the sklearn examples http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html